# Bootstrap collapse not working (+ and - signs is not changing)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am using bootstrap classes for collapse. When I click on the + symbol, it is not changing to the - symbol.

Here is my code. Please help me out.

```
var selectIds = $('#collapseOne1,#collapseTwo1');
$(function ($) {
    selectIds.on('show.bs.collapse hidden.bs.collapse', function () {          
        $(this).prev().find('.fa').toggleClass('fa-minus fa-plus');
    })
});

<div class="accordion" >
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">
                    <a id="submitid" class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseTwo1">
                        Submitted
                        <i class="fa fa-plus pull-right"></i>
                    </a>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <ul>
                        @foreach(var item in ViewBag.consultant)      
                        {
                            <li><strong>@item </strong></li>
                        }
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading active">
                <h3 class="panel-title">
                    <a id="rejectid" class="accordion-toggle active" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseOne1">
                        Rejected
                        <i class="fa fa-minus pull-right"></i>
                    </a>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne1" class="panel-collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="media accordion-inner">
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <ul>
                                @foreach(var item in ViewBag.consultant)      
                                {
                                    <li><strong>@item </strong></li>
                                }

                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>     
    </div>
</div>
```

When I click on 'Submitted' the + symbol is still showing. Not changed to - symbol.

```
<script src="~/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Why are you including `min` and `normal js` files for `jquery-ui` and `jquery-validate`? either of one is enough! Place `jquery-1.7.1.js` above all the other `js` files

Comment: I removed those js files.still not getting...

Comment: A demo of the issue you are having would help enormously.

Comment: Paste the rendered html instead to test it..

Comment: i didn't understand..rendered html?

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working fiddle with the exact code you are providing so I guess the problem lies in the way you load the js files, do you have **any errors in your browser console?**

http://jsfiddle.net/196dyxk8/

```
var selectIds = $('#collapseOne1,#collapseTwo1');
$(function ($) {
    selectIds.on('show.bs.collapse hidden.bs.collapse', function () {          
        $(this).prev().find('.fa').toggleClass('fa-minus fa-plus');
    })
});
```

Comment: i applied some styles

Comment: <style type="text/css">
    .accordion h2{
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.panel-default{
  border-color: transparent;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading,
.panel{
  background-color: #444; 
  border:0 none;
  box-shadow:none;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading+.panel-collapse .panel-body{
  background: #fff;
  color: #858586;
  border-left:1px solid;
  border-right:1px solid;
  border-bottom:1px solid;
}

.panel-body{
  padding: 5px 5px;
}

.panel-group .panel+.panel{
  margin-top: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
}

.panel-group .panel{
  border-radius: 0;
}

Comment: in controller:   var a = from s in apar.Consultant_Master
                    select s.FirstName; ViewBag.consultant = a.ToList();
            return View();